# JRebel and Weblogic fails at second start

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, weblogic, jrebel

i have a strange issue concerning JRebel and WebLogic (12.1.1). I'm using IntelliJ but the issue reproduces on Eclipse as well.

The first time i deployed my project on my weblogic server using Jrebel, everything went well. However, since the first deploy, i've been unable to deploy my app anymore. I have this strange java class not found error during the build:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/oracle/injection/integration/CDIModuleExtension$JrWebBeanRescanCallback
```

The process is the same with debug mode. I've been able to deploy the app on debug mode with jrebel the first time, and can't deploy it anymore as well...

If anyone has already experienced this issue and have any tips that could help me...

Thanks in advance,

Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is indeed caused by JRebel. I was able to reproduce it with the current latest release (7.1.7). Fortunately, it should already be fixed in the latest [nightly build](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/nightly-build/) and will be included in the next release.